# ASP.NET WebForms and Bootstrap compatibility issue in IE 10

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have a project created by Visual Studio 2013 from ASP.NET WebForms application template. Everything was fine till I updated my browser to IE 10. 
In IE 10 I found out that some controls are invisible when a page is opened.
These controls are located inside standard Bootstrap tab panel. For example:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
   <label class="control-label-wide">Dealer's code:</label>
   <asp:Label ID="DealerCodeLabel" runat="server"  />
</div>
```

When I select these elements by mouse they become visible.
In other browsers everything works well and in IE 8 too. 
I've updated Bootstrap, jQuery, jQuery UI to latest versions but it didn't help.
How do I resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you confirm that the javascript is running ? and rendered on page, if not then you probably do not have update the browser list and did not recognize the IE10 and did not render the javascript

Comment: Yes, the javascript is running and other elements that outside the tab panel are displayed correctly. jQuery plugins such as jQuery Validation work well. The problem as I can guess occurs when controls are rendered inside tab panel. When I press F12 in IE 10 and change browser mode to IE 8 then everything works fine.

Comment: render this Request.Browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString(); on page to see what you get - and Request.Browser.JavaScript.ToString()

Comment: EcmaScriptVersion shows: 3.0

Comment: ok, then maybe you should look at the css... hard to help you....  use the browser tools to see whats going wrong with the css, maybe also check if you do not have forget to close some tags